# TeamCity two builds using the same checkout directory keeps cleaning the folder

Tags: build, teamcity

I have two different build configurations sharing the same destination folder and pointing to the same source control branch.
Whenever I run a build in one of them, the destination folder is cleaned out before getting the source control files. That makes my compilation fail because the reference DLLs are not under source control.
Is there a way to avoid the clean-up of the folder? I just want the files that have changed to be updated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can override the "Working directory" by specifying in the build configuration.
2. Also you can set dependencies between the builds, by placing one build as a parent and another one as a child.
3. You can avoid 'clean' for the first build which gets normally triggered first. But this option is not ideal as it may have other implications in the build.

Also make sure to check the checkout directory where the files are getting imported to. Seems this is also in the directory in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vijayan. The point "2" gave me the clue to work it out. :)